# How do I solve TypeError: pow() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)?

Tags: python, rsa

I made a small program that can solve RSA math questions. One part of the program checks if the ciphertext is needed, and if the plaintext, e and n are given.

When executing the code I get an error: 
TypeError: pow() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
Even though pow() can take 3 arguments https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/pow

```py
if "ciphertext" in NeededObjDict and "plaintext" in GivenObjDict and "e" in GivenObjDict and "n" in GivenObjDict:
        OutputCiphertext = str(pow(GivenPlaintext, GivenE, GivenN))
        print('ciphertext = ',OutputCiphertext)
```

Comment: What version of python are you using? This could be related to changes to the int types in python 3

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7.2

Comment: Do you import any functions or are `pow`'s arguments not all `int` type? I'm thinking it could be related to this: https://github.com/PythonCharmers/python-future/issues/87

Comment: I just import pow from math

Comment: See my answer below for an explanation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I found the reason for your issue. The built-in `pow` function takes three arguments as seen [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html?highlight=pow#pow). However the `math.pow` function takes in two arguments, as seen [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/math.html?highlight=math%20pow#math.pow)

I would check if you're importing `pow` from `math` somewhere.

Comment: No problem. Note that the math.pow function can handle floating point numbers, while the built-in pow only works with integers (and it only takes  a third argument if you're raising to a positive power)

Comment: The built-in pow works just fine with two floats. I think you meant "only works with three arguments if all three are integers and the second is non-negative".